# What am I missing in my foreach and/or echo

Tags: joomla, foreach, echo

I am trying to cycle through the results of my query to display in table format on my page.
What am I missing in my foreach and my echo to cycle through the results in my display table.

```
{source 0}
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if (!$user->guest)
$name = $user->username;

$db =& JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "
     SELECT image_url
     FROM #__image_data
     WHERE user_name = '$name'";

$db->setQuery($query);

$list = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($list as $item){
     $item->image_url;
}
?>
   <td><?php echo $item->image_url;?></td><br/>
   <td><?php echo $item->image_url;?></td><br/>
   <td><?php echo $item->image_url;?></td><br/>
{/source}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            {source 0}
            <?php
            $user =& JFactory::getUser();
            if (!$user->guest)
            $name = $user->username;

            $db =& JFactory::getDbo();

            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query = "
                 SELECT image_url
                 FROM #__image_data
                 WHERE user_name = '$name'";

            $db->setQuery($query);

            $list = $db->loadObjectList();
            foreach ($list as $item){
                 echo "<td>".$item->image_url."</td><br/>";
            }
            ?>

            {/source}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loops through and get the `<td>` as below.

Method 1 - Here you don't have to concatenate since you are using `""`

```
$list = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($list as $item){
     echo "<td> $item->image_url </td><br/>";
}
```

Method 2

```
$list = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($list as $item){
     echo '<td>'.$item->image_url'.</td><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you also .. I ended up going with `code`echo "<td>"."<img src='$item->image_url'>" . $item->image_date ."</td><br/>"; Not sure if that would also work and not sure what the concantenate is .. I would like to change the format of the date output from 2013-01-01 22:06:34 to 01-01-2013 .. not sure if i do that in the database or if i can manipulate the output from the iamge_date table